# How can detect the Left Ventricle (LV) Cavity into the MR dicom file?

Tags: image-processing

This is MR Modality Link

[MR Modality](http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1365578059)

In this file where i find the LV Cavity in above link file. Also how to draw Tumor Marker from over it

Comment: This seems off topic, but if you remove all the jargon from this question and translate to a question about image processing or some other signal processing topic, someone might have an answer.

Comment: Are you asking how to perform image processing on MR/CT images to identify the left ventricle?  Where did you see this information about the CAD tools?  Because it sounds like that should tell you how to do it.

Comment: Yes Its part of image processing on MR images to identify the left ventricle?

Comment: also I edited my post

Comment: You could use ImageJ in order to open the DICOM image as well as draw the tumor marker over it 'manually'.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking at this DICOM now and it is very hard to tell where I am in the brain (since there is only one slice). Anyhow, tumours tend to be bright irregularities. The thing I *think* is a tumour certainly isn't in the LV.

You can just draw an ROI over it using something like FSLVIEW if you are planning to do it manually, or you can have some fun and use something that looks for irregularities across hemispheres in the edges as detected by an algorithm.

http://www.medicalimagingandgraphics.com/article/S0895-6111(11)00079-6/abstract

Hope this helps...